# php input type text not giving new value

Tags: php, caching, cookies, input, history

Ok here is my case

1. i have  and its value is get from mysql
   *let's say its value is 500.91
2. i changed its value from phpmyadmin into 500.9
3. at phpmyadmin the value succesfully changed into 500.9
4. but at my google chrome the value is still 500.91, i have press f5 for refresh and it's still 500.91

there are 2 option to have the value changed
1. clear all of cache, history and cookies
2. wait a couple of days and it will changed

my question is

How to automatically change the value without clear all history manually or wait for couple days?
please help me

*database changed but php display not changed

---

**Edit (by Dinistro):**

here is the code which was added in the comments:

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM surat_jalan WHERE tanggal >= '$tanggal1' 
AND tanggal <= '$tanggal2 23:59' ORDER BY tanggal ASC"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
?> 
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="volume" value="<?php echo($row['volume']); ?>" />
    </td> 
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Do you use some GET or POST variables to show the value?

Comment: Did you reload the page? Unless you use polling with AJAX, web pages don't change until you reload them.

Comment: @Dinistro i use GET method

Comment: @Barmar I have reload the page but the value is still unchanged

Comment: @log1c  <?php  
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `surat_jalan` WHERE tanggal >= '$tanggal1' AND tanggal <= '$tanggal2 23:59' ORDER BY tanggal ASC");  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  
    ?>  
<td><input type="text" name="volume" value="<?php echo($row['volume']); ?>" /></td>  
<?php } ?>

Comment: And do you use this get-parameter to print out the value?

Comment: @Dinistro
thank you helping me writing my code im still newbie trying double space to get line break but cannot 

jalan1.php?tujuan=ALL&tanggal1=2014-03-01&tanggal2=2014-03-31

that is like that i get the parameter just for my query

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$display = <<<EOF_;
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
EOF_;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM surat_jalan WHERE tanggal >= '$tanggal1' 
AND tanggal <= '$tanggal2 23:59' ORDER BY tanggal ASC"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$display .= <<<EOF_;
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" name="volume" value="$row['volume']" />
  </td>
 </tr> 
EOF_;
}
$display .= <<<EOF_;
</table>
EOF_;
echo"$display";
?>
```

Comment: Please add some context into why and how your answer solves the problem posed in the question